# How to remove certain key value pairs form a Object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have used Lodash to get to this structure where i needed to group by id .

The grouping by works fine but i want to add more properties to the head of the group by field like its name and domain, from the nested object , how do i do that.

**Extra** - Also In future if i need to Filter the contents inside the nested object like using status or by the publisher name how do i add that . Very new to Javascript

```
 let result = _.chain(value)
      .groupBy('pubId')
      .pairs()
      .map(function(currentItem) {
        return _.object(_.zip(['publisherId', 'targetting'], currentItem));
      })
      .value();
```

The data returned by this

```js
{
      "publisherId": "17",
       // add name , domain , here
      "targetting": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "pubId": 17, // remove this
          "type": 18,
          "value": "google.com,yahoo.com",
          "status": 12,
          "createTs": null, // remove this
          "updateTs": null,// remove this
          "createUser": null,// remove this
          "updateUser": null,// remove this
          "percentage": 0,// remove this
          "rtbSspPublishers": { // remove this
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Tom's Hardware",
            "domain": "www.tomshardware.com",
            "extPublisherId": 17
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "pubId": 17,
          "type": 14,
          "value": "Sports,Fashion",
          "status": 12,
          "createTs": null,
          "updateTs": null,
          "createUser": null,
          "updateUser": null,
          "percentage": 0,
          "rtbSspPublishers": {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Tom's Hardware",
            "domain": "www.tomshardware.com",
            "extPublisherId": 17
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "pubId": 17,
          "type": 11,
          "value": "Sports,Fashion",
          "status": 12,
          "createTs": null,
          "updateTs": null,
          "createUser": null,
          "updateUser": null,
          "percentage": 0,
          "rtbSspPublishers": {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Tom's Hardware",
            "domain": "www.tomshardware.com",
            "extPublisherId": 17
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I need to remove certain properties from the nested grouping how do i acheive that using lodash i am using lodash 3.0.0 .Please help thanks

Comment: just use the `delete` keyword. E.g. `var obj = { a: "a" }; delete obj.a;`

Comment: i want to embed it in the same lodash function is that possible

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the `result` again and *delete* those properties which are not required.

For example

```
var propsToBeDeleted = [ "createTs", "updateTs" ]; //array of properties to be deleted
result = result.map( function(item){
   propsToBeDeleted.forEach( function(prop){
      delete item[prop];
   }); 
   return item;
});
```

Or try updating your lodash code as

```
let result = _.chain(value)
  .groupBy('pubId')
  .pairs()
  .map(function(currentItem) {
     var item =  _.object(_.zip(['publisherId', 'targetting'], currentItem));
     propsToBeDeleted.forEach( function(prop){
        delete item[prop];
     }); 
    return item;
  })
  .value();
```

Comment: i want to embed it in the same lodash function is that possible

Comment: but inside that i am doing this `return _.object(_.zip(['publisherId', 'targetting'], currentItem));` untill this the object is not prepared ?

Comment: also how do i add more properties to the top of group by

Comment: Check the example I have shared